# Unable to connect to telnet server

Tags: telnet

I am trying to setup a telnet server on a windows 7 PC
Locally I can login by typing the followings:

telnet localhost

However when I am trying to login from a remote PC I am getting the following error:

```
Failure in initializing the telnet session. Shell process may not have been launched.

Telnet Server has closed the connection
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I check the PC event log, which has the followings error message:

```
Error in creating CMD proces. System Error: Access is denied.
```

How can I enable telnet on the local network?

Comment: I can read  the error message but I don't  know where can I fix this.  I newer used windows. I am happy with Ubuntu.

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because it is literally one of the most awful ideas on the planet.

Comment: I know it is an awful  idea. There are security  issue  if it is connected to the internet, however the pc is behind  a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309523

It is targeted at Windows XP x64, but would be worth trying in your case. Other than that I would suggest trying it with UAC (User Account Control) disabled and see if that helps.

EDIT: Per the comment below, here are the steps to fix the issue according to Microsoft

```
At a command prompt on the host that is running the Telnet service, type cd %systemroot%\system32, and then press ENTER.
Type net stop tlntsvr, and then press ENTER.
Type tlntsvr /unregserver, and then press ENTER.
Type tlntsvr /service, and then press ENTER.
Type net start tlntsvr, and then press ENTER. Telnet connections to the Telnet service should now be accepted.
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Very prohetic, the linked page doesn't exist anymore (or was moved). I don't get why this question was closed though, I have this exact problem in one of my client machines. :(